# Check if resourse for videoview from internet could be played

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm trying from play video on the internet using videoview :

```
String path1="http://someserverhere.com
Uri uri=Uri.parse(path1);
VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView01);
video.setVideoURI(uri);
video.start();
```

How could I know the video resourse could be played (to handle exception), so far i tried:

```
   try {
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setDataSource(this, uri);
        mp.release();
    }
  catch (Exceptione) {

   }
```

But this code - mediaplayer hang my screen.
Any suggesiton on this? Tks a lot.

Comment: have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check if the file is exist with header request

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public static boolean isFileExist(String URLName){
    try {
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        //you may also need HttpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)
        HttpURLConnection con =
                (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URLName).openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know to check if the file is video file?

Comment: As far as i know you can't. Btw you can check from the extension of the file from the url, although it is not accurate. Or you can set onErrorListener on MediaPlayer, so it will catch any error if the video fail to load

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by checking the width and height of video by using following code.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mRetriever.setDataSource(context, uri);
Bitmap frame = mRetriever.getFrameAtTime();

int width = frame.getWidth();
int height = frame.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

Play video from Web Full code.

**Note:** Add Internet permission in manifest.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    VideoView videoview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        String VideoURL = "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4";
        videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Android Video Streaming Demo");
        pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

        try {
            // Start the MediaController
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
            // Get the URL from String VideoURL
            Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
            videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        videoview.requestFocus();
        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                videoview.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```